# Ajax data management

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, ajax, database

I'm not really comfortable working with Ajax as I just started using it. 
My question is as follows:

What is the best way to manage data fetched using Ajax?

I have a script that fetches data from a database and displays it in different ways depending on the users filters and order criterias. So far, I query the database for every requests and was thinking if it could be better to fetch all data at once, store it in an array of objects and run queries like ordering and category filtering locally using Javascript.

Any gains in termms of speed and/or performance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Show an example first. An example of the data that is fetched from database and the required way to arrange them. You can use XML or JSON or straight JavaScript object. the question is which one do you like to work with? I would choose the returned data from database to be in XML format. Show us an example of code where you don't know what to do.